# Comparing two tables in same database and take difference into another table without repeating the entries

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am doing a project on RFID reader using SQL Server, Visual Studio, C#. I have a database called `rfid` with three tables table1, table2 and table3.

`table1` is filled with the details of the fixed tags and those entries are not going to change. Every `rfid` tag has a identical code calling EPC number and we can identify them with it.

`Table3` is filling with the entries of the tag which are read by the RFID reader. The only change between table1 and table3 is table1 is fixed table and we have given those entries early. But table3 is always filled with the reading operation of the reader.Then it takes few seconds to fill.

`Table2` is filled with the difference entries in table1 and table3, when they are compared. I tried usual table compare method and take entries to the table2, but the issue is the entries are repeating in the table2 because the reader reads the tags continuously. I want to stop that. And other thing is since it is taken few seconds to filled table3, it shows some wrong tags as the difference.

As an example I tried usual table compare method and take entries to the table2, but the issue is the entries are repeating in the table2 because the reader reads the tags continuously. I want to stop that. And other thing is since it is taken few seconds to filled table3, it shows some wrong tags as the difference. As an example. Let's say there are 10 entries in the table1. And we give same 8 tags to read also including in table2. SO now I am expecting only two difference tag entries in table2 according to my code. But there are more than two entries. The reason for that, table3 is filling one by one or any way but not all the 8 tags at once. Then once a tag detail comes to the table3, the comparison is begun. Then it takes the difference as rest of nine tags.

Now I want to stop those two interrupting scenarios.

```
con = new SqlConnection(Constants.ConnectionString);
con.Open();

SqlCommand comp = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table2 (EPC, identificationcount, RSSI) SELECT EPC, identificationcount, RSSI FROM table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table3 WHERE table1.EPC = table3.EPC)", con);
comp.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: This is happening because you're filling your table2 continuously.  You have to clean table2 before you insert new entries (DELETE FROM table2). Also, you should do it (cleanup and inserts) in a single transaction.

Comment: this thing is being complex with that RFID reader. think table2 (the difference table) is epty now. And i start the reader. It inserts one by one tag details into table3. Comparing part is processing. Now difference of table3 and fixed table1 is inserted into table2. if we can take the the difference after filled the table3, this issue will be ok. but it is not practical with whole process.

Comment: why do you need table2 to be persistent at all anyway? Maybe instead you can create a View that will return the difference between table1 and table 3?

Comment: Do You know if You have complete data for RFID in table1 in other table? Or You don't know this. You say there are 8 tags sometimes. DO you know it whene there is only 7, that this is not complete?

Answer (score 0):

You can make views using join with Table1 and Table3. I use table variable so there's @ symbol in front of the table name. You can omit the @ symbol if you use real tables.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (RFID INT)
DECLARE @Table3 TABLE (RFID INT)

INSERT @Table1 VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
INSERT @Table3 VALUES (1), (1), (1), (2), (2), (5), (6), (6)

-- only missing RFID in Table3
SELECT T1.*
FROM @Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN @Table3 T3 ON T1.RFID = T3.RFID
WHERE T3.RFID IS NULL

-- missing RFID in both tables
SELECT DISTINCT T1.*, T3.*
FROM @Table1 T1 FULL OUTER JOIN @Table3 T3 ON T1.RFID = T3.RFID
WHERE T3.RFID IS NULL OR T1.RFID IS NULL
```